# why do we need the SUID permission?

Tags: permissions, setuid, passwd

Please read this long intro to understand my concern for why we need the SUID permission for executable binary file.

- A process in Linux uses its EUID to know the *effective User ID* of itself.
- This user's permission is used to decide how this process interacts with other files (ex. whether this process can write to a file)

Consider the scenario with changing password via `/usr/bin/passwd`

**Real life Linux**

- Passwords are stored in `/etc/shadow`. This file belongs to `root` with permission (`rw-------`)
- *If* `$passwd` has permission `rwx--x--x`, this means only root can change the logic of **passwd program**.
- When `userA` runs the program, a `passwd` process starts with **RUID** = **EUID** = userA

Result is: the program will run. A `passwd` **process** is started but it won't be able to change the password since its **EUID** is *userA* and *userA* can't write to `/etc/shadow`.

This is when **the need for SUID permission** arrives. **SUID** allows setting **EUID** of a process upon execution of a binary to create that process. the **EUID** will be set to the owner of that binary file.

- Setting **SUID permission** for owner of `/usr/bin/passwd` makes **EUID** of any `passwd` **process** started by any user takes the **EUID** of `root`
- Since `root` can write to `/etc/shadow`, any user can use the `passwd` program to start a `passwd` **process** which can make changes to `/etc/shadow`

> There is **SUID permission** because in Linux, **EUID** of a process is not hard set to the owner of the executable binary file (which when run, will create that process)

**My ideal Linux**

> No need for **SUID permission**. If executable file *binA* is created (and owned) by *userA*, any users who can execute *binA* will create a **process** with **EUID** = *userA*.

In the context of the changing password scenario, the logic of this idea is as follows:

- *root* is the owner of `/usr/bin/passwd` and only *root* can change its logic.
- The logic inside `/usr/bin/passwd` lets a user change its password only and not others'.
- Other users can't modify `/usr/bin/passwd`, only *root* can.
- `/etc/shadow` can only be writen to by `root`

Result is: An unprivileged user `userA` can execute `$passwd`. He will create a `passwd` **process**. This process has **EUID** = *root* so it can write to the `shadow` file.

With this theory, we can achieve: everyone can change their own password (and only their own password) without **SUID permission**.

Comment: in your system where "If executable file binA is created (and owned) by userA, any users who can execute binA will create a process with EUID = userA",  who should own `/bin/sh` and `/usr/bin/vi` ?

Comment: I would say root should own. Since it's inside /bin filesystem and according to FHS, /bin is for commands that may be used by both the system administrator and by users, I think it makes sense if it is owned by root.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that anyone who ran the shell or vi would then have root permissions?

Comment: Thank you. I see where you're pointing at, so in my system, if root owns /bin/sh or /usr/bin/vi, anyone can use vi as root and modify files only root should be able to modify. It makes perfect sense. Please give me some more time to reflect on your response and my confusion).

Comment: I have contemplated on both of your responses, thank you very much. Since sebasth put the answer up there, I'll accept it as the answer, although @Mark Plotnick's comment would have been satisfied. Thank you both once again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question at all but a discussion/proposal of OS features.

Comment: I did not want to make a proposal or discussion to the Linux OS. I simply wanted to understand the logic of the existence of the SUID permission. I understood how it works, but not why it was invented or maybe what problem it solved. By that logic, I think this is qualified as a question, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you're interested in this on a smaller scale, there is an MMORPG (well, not so M nowadays) called LambdaMOO where all code runs setuid to its owner. This is useful when everyone can write code that others can run and you want to minimize mischief.  The superuser-owned executables almost always do the Unix equivalent of `setuid(getruid())` first thing, and they are highly audited (and are only a few dozen kilobytes of source code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your examples explain how setuid works. However in your "ideal Linux" every executable would start with EUID of the owner of the executable, which would make every executable on your system a setuid executable.

This would clearly cause a lot of problems, to mention a few: every root owned executable would need to do UID checks and call `setuid()` to set process' EUID back to non-root if the program shouldn't have any additional privileges; users can not make executables available to another users, as the process would run with wrong EUID; configuration errors and bad practices would have critical consequences (such as `chmod 777` would now also allow access to any files owned by user). And these are more.

Normal permissions without setuid binaries need some other mechanism to allow unprivileged users to do privileged operations. Setuid binaries allow such privilege elevation and access control is implemented in program logic.

Answer (score 3):

The marked answer perfectly answered my question. What I put here is the extra logic that is helpful to me in explaining the existence of the **SUID permission** with regard to the changing password scenario.

1. In Linux, executable bin files are supposed to be run by different users.

   > For example, `/usr/bin/nano` is a bin for a text editor, it makes sense that this same executable bin file can be executed by different users (why make copies of the same bin file to each user's home filesystem?)
2. Even though many users should be able to use the same bin file, the process started by that bin file should have different permissions on a file.

   > For example, *userA* and *userB* should both be able to create two nano **process**es by executing the same `/usr/bin/nano` bin file. However, *userA*'s nano **process** should allow *userA* to modify his own files and only his own files and vice versa.

> This calls for a mechanism by which a **process** should apply the **same permission that the user who started that process** has on a file to that file (**instead of the permission of the user who owns the executable bin file** which was executed to create the process).

In Linux, each process has the **RUID**. The **RUID** is the id of the user which starts that process. By this logic, the **RUID** of a process should be the user whose permission on a file is used by that process (e.g. A process decides what it can do to a file based on what its **RUID** user can do to that file).

However, in the case of changing password, **RUID** alone isn't enough because:

1. `/etc/shadow` file can't be modified by anyone but *root*.
2. Any users want to change password need to do that through executing `/usr/bin/passwd` executable bin file. This program's logic makes sure an underprivileged user can change his and only his password.
3. No users except root can change this logic since only root can write to this bin file.
4. If *userA* executes `/usr/bin/passwd`, he will start a `passwd` **process** whose **RUID** is *userA*.
5. However, since *userA* is not allowed to write to `/etc/shadow`, the `passwd` **process** he starts can't write to this file either.

> This calls for a mechanism by which a **process** decides its permissions to a file based on another user's permissions on that file (**instead of the permissions of the user who started the process**).

In Linux, the permission a process has on a file is taken from the permission the **EUID** has on that file.

With **EUID**, *root* can now use **SUID permission** to allow *userA* to start a `passwd` **process** that has the **EUID** set to *root*. This effectively allows the `passwd` **process** started by *userA* to modify the `/etc/shadow` file.